# Trying to understand details of the Application Resource assignment

Tags: wpf, dynamicresource

I have a ComboBox with ItemsSource="{DynamicResource testResource}". The testResource is the Application resource that I set in C# code.

What I have noticed is that if I load Window befor Application created, the resource is not loaded by ComboBox:

```
Window window = (Window)LoadXaml("Window1.xaml");
Application app = new Application();
```

This code works

```
Application app = new Application();
Window window = (Window)LoadXaml("Window1.xaml");
```

Also, even if I created the window befor the application, I can load resource latter in button click handler.

Can some one explain, what happens? Why the order matters?

Window1.xaml:

```
<Window 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{DynamicResource testResource}" SelectedIndex="0"></ComboBox>
        <Button x:Name='testButton'>Test</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

C#

```
class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        Window window = (Window)LoadXaml("Window1.xaml");
        Application app = new Application();
        SetupResource();

        (window.FindName("testButton") as Button).Click += new RoutedEventHandler(testButton_Click);
        window.Show();
        app.Run(window);
    }

    static void testButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SetupResource();
    }

    static void SetupResource()
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("Hola");
        list.Add("Mundo");
        Application.Current.Resources["testResource"] = list;
    }

    static object LoadXaml(string fileName)
    {
        return XamlReader.Load(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I would guess because the `Application`'s Resources are only loaded when the `Application` object is created. So if you want to access `testResource`, you need to do it after the call to `new Application()`.